# Вывод большего количества DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, база-данных, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

Как можно выводить много данных в одном chunk?

**example 1: (chunk 1)**

```
data = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
for class in data.Pclass.unique():
    data[data['Pclass'] == class].groupby('Sex').Age.mean()
```

**example 2: (chunk 2)**

```
data.Age.hist()
data.Fare.hist()
//
data.Age.describe(), data.Fare.describe()
```

В первом примере, хотелось бы чтобы выводилось 3 DataFrame, но то что выполняется в цикле вообще не выводится.
Во втором примере, хотелось бы последовательно или в одну строку получить гистограммы распределения, а также получить основные статистические характеристики снизу поd гистограммами, ну или хотя бы последовательно.

Comment: Кажется, если в цикле обернуть dataframe в print, то получается, но со вторым все равно пока не ясно, но интересны варианты и без этого.

Answer (score 1):

## example 1

это можно сделать без цикла:

```
In [4]: data.groupby(["Pclass","Sex"])["Age"].mean().reset_index(name="Avg_Age")
Out[4]:
   Pclass     Sex    Avg_Age
0       1  female  34.611765
1       1    male  41.281386
2       2  female  28.722973
3       2    male  30.740707
4       3  female  21.750000
5       3    male  26.507589
```

## example 2

гистограммы можно получить так:

```
In [10]: cols = ["Age", "Pclass", "Fare"]

In [11]: from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

In [12]: scatter_matrix(data[cols], alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10), diagonal='hist')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ядерная оценка плотности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8):

```
In [13]: scatter_matrix(data[cols], alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10), diagonal='kde')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что первое без цикла - это просто как пример.

Comment: Второе вы не совсем меня поняли, я хотел бы в одном inpute иметь несколько графиков, строить гистограммы - я умею. :)

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, что значит в одном input?

Comment: Ну, вы запускаете строчки 12[In], 13[In]  и в каждом из них получаете график, а я хочу, чтобы я запускал код в одном чанке и у меня выводилось 2 графика сразу же.